# How can I get git history (date range) log to a file without author, date, commit message and commit hash

Tags: git, git-log, git-history

How can I get git history (date range) log to a file **without** author, date, commit message and commit hash?

Comment: `git log` without the ref (hash), author, date or commit message leaves nothing.  Could you give us a sample of the kind of log message(s) you want to capture?

Comment: Docs are here: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log You get a _lot_ of fine control over what the log shows.

Answer (score -2):

Found the way.

```
git log --since="2015-01-01" --until="2018-01-01" --pretty=format:""  -p > history-log.csv
```